# threejs (r72) point cloud movement

Tags: javascript, three.js, velocity, point-clouds, vertices

I'm working with the most recent r72 of THREEJS, and am trying to accomplish some effects that I used to do with pointclouds, which has now been replaced with the [Points](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Points) object.

I've set up a codepen http://codepen.io/shomanishikawa/pen/NGaWdW - both orbs are made by creating a geometry and pushing Vector3's to them.

I'd like to have individual points in the points object move at different velocities/directions, which was previously accomplished easily by setting something like

`particle.velocity.y = 20`

Which now seems to have no effect.

The orb on the left uses a [BufferGeometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry) with a [ShaderMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial)

The orb on the right uses a [Geometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry) with a [PointsMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/PointsMaterial)

How can I set velocities on individual points so I can have them orbit around the radius instead of just rotating the parent Points object?

I'd like to accomplish this with a regular Geometry if possible, since I'd like finer control of moving the vertices individually. Provided examples of both just in case it's only feasible with one version.